# Why does .foreach behave differently than for...of when executing a recursive callback?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, foreach, for-of-loop

I'm writing a recursive depth-first graph traversal using an adjacency list, which is an object containing vertices as keys and an array of each keys neighbors as values. A helper function is called recursively to visit all neighbors of an initial vertex, and then all neighbors of those neighbors, etc.

For some reason, using a "for...of" loop to iterate through each neighbor array is not working properly. The helper function will be called on a neighbor of a neighbor of a neighbor, but then when the base case is reached, the helper function does not seem to be called on the other neighbors of the initial neighbor, so you end up with dead-ends that are never reached.

```
  function depthFirstRecursiveTraversal(initialVertex) {
    const adjacencyList = {
      A: ['B', 'C'],
      B: ['A', 'D'],
      C: ['A', 'E'],
      D: ['B', 'E', 'F'],
      E: ['C', 'D', 'F'],
      F: ['D', 'E']
    };
    let visited = {};
    let vertexList = [];

    function dfsHelper(v) {
      if (!v) return null;
      vertexList.push(v);
      visited[v] = true;

      // Why does a for-of loop fail here? Recursion fails to reach all vertices
      //for (const neighbor of adjacencyList[v]) {
      //  if (!visited[neighbor]) return dfsHelper(neighbor);
      //}

      // But using forEach instead works!
       adjacencyList[v].forEach(neighbor => {
         if (!visited[neighbor]) return dfsHelper(neighbor);
       });

    }
    dfsHelper(initialVertex);

    return vertexList;
  }
```

Calling depthFirstRecursiveTraversal(A) returns [ 'A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'C', 'F' ], which is correct.

But if you comment out the forEach and comment in the for...of loop, it returns [ 'A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'C' ] -- the 'F' vertex is never reached.

For reference, this is what the graph looks like:

```
         A
       /   \
      B     C
      |     |
      D --- E
       \   /
         F
```

Can anyone tell me why for...of fails, but foreach works?

Comment: `if (!visited[neighbor]) return dfsHelper(neighbor);` doesn't stop forEach from iterating the whole array - whereas in a `for` loop, the return would terminate the iteration (by returning from the function) - by the way, in the code you presented, in forEach, you could equally do `if (!visited[neighbor]) dfsHelper(neighbor);` with the same result (i.e. no return)

Comment: Hi Stuart, could you describe why the depth first is `['A','B','D','E','C','F']` and not `['A','B','D','F','E','C']`.  The way I read the chart, 'F' is the lowest node and if D is connected to both E and F, it seems the left path is traversed first.

Comment: Now looking at `adjacencyList` in the code (particularly nodes 'D' and 'E'), I understand why that is the expected result. I'm curious if that diagram matches that flow, given the TDLR flow direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the `for` loop, `return` will terminate the entire `dfsHelper` function. In contrast, inside the `forEach` callback, `return` just terminates the callback.

The return value doesn't matter here, and returning doesn't achieve anything except introduce this bug. Best to remove the `return` from both versions - and if you do that, the `for..of` works fine:

```js
function depthFirstRecursiveTraversal(initialVertex) {
  const adjacencyList = {
    A: ['B', 'C'],
    B: ['A', 'D'],
    C: ['A', 'E'],
    D: ['B', 'E', 'F'],
    E: ['C', 'D', 'F'],
    F: ['D', 'E']
  };
  let visited = {};
  let vertexList = [];

  function dfsHelper(v) {
    if (!v) return null;
    vertexList.push(v);
    visited[v] = true;

    for (const neighbor of adjacencyList[v]) {
      if (!visited[neighbor]) dfsHelper(neighbor);
    }

  }
  dfsHelper(initialVertex);

  return vertexList;
}
console.log(depthFirstRecursiveTraversal('A'));
```

Comment: Nice work.  And if he did want to keep those `return` statements for some unknown reason, he could encapsulate the scope in an IIFE:  `(function(neighbor){ return dfsHelper(neighbor); })(neighbor)` -- PS stick to the answer and don't do this